# animated image in notification android 12 update

Tags: android, notifications, animated-gif

How to achieve this feature? : In **Android 12**, you can now enrich your app’s notification experience by providing **animated images** in MessagingStyle() and BigPictureStyle() notifications. Also, your app can now enable users **to send image messages** when they reply to messages from the notification shade.

link from official doc : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features#enriched_image_support_for_notifications

Comment: You can get bitmap from your animated image and use [this](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded)

Comment: I had tried that, but it looks like normal image not gif

Comment: @FrenyChristian Did you get animated images in notifications working?